# excel function to count occurances of text in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

please give me  the complete code for me to copy and paste in order to get the results in column B.  please note that my actual spreadsheet contains a lot more than just 3 different variables for column A. 
thank you very much Nathaniel

1  A        B
2 Country    count of occurance
3 USA    3
4 Canada     2
5 Mexico     1
6 USA    3
7 Canada     2
8 USA    3

Answer (score 1):

Look at the help for the countif function. You can use =countif(range, "USA") for static values to count of =countif(range, A1) to count whatever is in cell A1.